# Runtime error when calling a subroutine with an object as argument excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, arguments, userform

**Scenario**

I have a userform whereby it has a Combobox with some options. There is a Textbox as well in the same userform. When I select a certain option in the combobox, I need the text box to be disabled as well as change background colour.

**My Codes**

Following are my codes. `poType` is the combobox name and `unitPrice` is the textbox name

```
Public Sub poType_Change()    
    If mainPage.poType.Value = "FOC" Then
        disabling (unitPrice)
    Else
        enabling (unitPrice)
    End If
End Sub
```

Following is the subroutines disabling and enabling

```
Sub disabling(ByVal objectToDisable As Object)
    objectToDisable.Enabled = False
    objectToDisable.BackColor = &H80000003
End Sub

Sub enabling(ByVal objectToEnable As Object)
    objectToEnable.Enabled = True
    objectToEnable.BackColor = &H80000005
End Sub
```

However, it is showing runtime error (424 object required) when I am executing this code. Anyone knows the reason?

Comment: Why is poType_Change public? What is mainPage? Is that the form?

Comment: poType_Change is public. mainPage is the userform where the combobox and textbox placed

Comment: Don’t use parentheses when calling a Sub

Comment: Right, remove the "( ...)".  It will evaluate the object to the default and that is the value of the textbox. You should also replace mainPage with Me.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thank you. It solved my problem with the above code

Comment: @Storax Thank you. By the way, my code is working even when gave mainPage.xxx. Is there any particular reason why need to use Me. instead of mainPage. since both are working fine for my case?

Comment: See https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Able to find rootcause of this problem. The above problem can be solved in two ways

**Method 1**

Need to add **call** when calling a subroutine

```
Public Sub poType_Change()    
    If mainPage.poType.Value = "FOC" Then
        call disabling (unitPrice)
    Else
        call enabling (unitPrice)
    End If
End Sub

Sub disabling(ByVal objectToDisable As Object)
    objectToDisable.Enabled = False
    objectToDisable.BackColor = &H80000003
End Sub

Sub enabling(ByVal objectToEnable As Object)
    objectToEnable.Enabled = True
    objectToEnable.BackColor = &H80000005
End Sub
```

**Method 2**

**Don't use parenthesis for arguments**. But for this case, **don't add call** in front

```
Public Sub poType_Change()    
    If mainPage.poType.Value = "FOC" Then
        disabling unitPrice
    Else
        enabling unitPrice
    End If
End Sub

Sub disabling(ByVal objectToDisable As Object)
    objectToDisable.Enabled = False
    objectToDisable.BackColor = &H80000003
End Sub

Sub enabling(ByVal objectToEnable As Object)
    objectToEnable.Enabled = True
    objectToEnable.BackColor = &H80000005
End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend to also replace mainPage with Me!